# K8s does strange networking stuff that breaks application designs

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, connection-refused

I discovered a strange behavior with K8s networking that can break some applications designs completely.

I have two pods and one Service

- Pod 1 is a stupid Reverse Proxy (I don't know the implementation)
- Pod 2 is a Webserver
- The mentioned Service belongs to pod 2, the webserver

After the initial start of my stack I discovered that Pod 1 - the Reverse Proxy is not able to reach the webserver on the first attempt for some reason, ping is working fine and curl also.
Now I tried wget mywebserver inside of Pod 1 - Reverse Proxy and got back the following:

```
 wget mywebserver
--2020-11-16 20:07:37--  http://mywebserver/
Resolving mywebserver (mywebserver)... 10.244.0.34, 10.244.0.152, 10.244.1.125, ...
Connecting to mywebserver (mywebserver)|10.244.0.34|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to mywebserver (mywebserver)|10.244.0.152|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to mywebserver (mywebserver)|10.244.1.125|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to mywebserver (mywebserver)|10.244.2.177|:80... connected.
```

Where 10.244.2.177 is the Pod IP of the Webserver.
The problem to me it seems is that the Reverse-Proxy does not try to trigger the attempt to forward the package twice, instead it only tries once where it fails like in the wget cmd above and the request gets dropped as the backed is not reachable due to fancy K8s IPtables stuff it seems...

If I configure the reverse-proxy not to use the Service DNS-name for load-off and instead use the Pod IP (10.244.2.177) everything is working fine and as expected.

I already tried this with a variety of CNI Providers like: Flannel, Calico, Canal, Weave and also Cilium as Kube-Proxy is not used with Cilium but all of them failed and all of them doing fancy routing nobody clearly understands out-of-the-box. So my question is how can I make K8s routing work immediately at this point? I already have reimplemented my whole stack to docker-swarm just to see if it works, and it does, flawlessly! So this issue has to do something with K8s routing scheme it seems.

Just to exclude misconfiguration from my side I also tried this with different ready-to-use K8s solutions like managed K8s from Digital-Ocean and or self-hosted RKE. All have the same behavior.

Does somebody maybe have a Idea what the problem might be and how to fix this behavior of K8s?

I might also be very useful to know what actually happens at the wget request, as this remains a mystery to me.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what are those IPs that don't respond `10.244.0.34, 10.244.0.152, 10.244.1.125`?

Comment: That's the question, I have no Idea at all! But at least they all are part of the Pod's CIDR range of K8s

Comment: show `kubectl describe` for the service you're connecting to.

Comment: It seems that the mentioned IP that wget try's to connect to are coming from the service, kubectl output is:

Endpoints:         10.244.0.34:80,10.244.0.152:10.244.1.125:80 ...

Comment: I already tried to give the Service a static ClusterIP but with no success onto this routing problem

Comment: It seems that any type of program that does not try to reconnect fails in this scenario, not only wget. I have a similar issue with a reverse-proxy that also just tries to connect once and then completely fails ...

Comment: So you have multiple containers there, do you expect just one? If you have deployed one pod - it should be just one IP address there. If it's more than that - your service definition is incorrect: it selects more pods than it should.

Comment: Currently I have setup my Deployment with just replica set to 1 so in the end there is also just one Pod behind the service/kube-proxy. As already mentioned, I have no Idea where those IPs are coming from. To me, Just one IP should be in place and not 4 ...

Comment: could it be that CoreDNS is building some redundant entrys for the webserver service and Kube-proxy gets multiple IP's on that?

Comment: No, if you see 4 endpoints there - it means your service selected those 4 pods.`kubectl get pods -A -o wide`

Comment: Yes there is only one. I fixed this issue by Removing ClusterIP: None from my deployment.yaml of the webserver, No I only have one Ip in place

Comment: You did not fix anything: you switched from headless to cluster ip service, but endpoints are still there. As I mentioned - there are multiple pods selected by your service. `kubectl get pods -A -o wide`. There is your word vs kubernetes word: I trust kubernetes more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224666/discussion-between-sunwave121-and-zerkms).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had several misconfigurations at my K8s Deployment.
I first removed ClusterIP: None as this leads to the behavior wget shows above at my question. Beside I've set app: and tier: wrong at my deployment. Anyways now everything is working fine and wget has a proper connection.

Thanks again

Comment: please follow this tutorial [Connect a Front End to a Back End Using a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) it's quite a good example how to connect frontend with backend using k8s services. As stated in the comments from k8s perspective it should be more investigated but according to the provided examples it's quite hard to figure out where (behind the scene) is the problem.